# android compare arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, compare

As I am not the best in android development, I tried something that works for me and for friend's mobile, but i have some reports from market that it doesn't work for all devices maybe and do wrong compare. Anyway. the project is simple, it grabs an order from sql and in the game the player try to finish it. So I have 2 arrays. I call this at start:

```
    final String[] combo = new String[] {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}; 
    final String[] order1 = new String[] {"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};


    for(int i = 0; i < combo.length; i++) {
        combo[i] = new String();
        combo[i] = "0";
        order1[i] = new String();
        order1[i] = "0";
    }
```

and during the game if the player clicks a button it changes the value of combo, for example, combo[7] = "1";

When he click the final button I check that 2 arrays with this

```
String IsSame = compareOrder(combo, order1);
```

and then

```
   if (IsSame.equals("TRUE")) {

   // commands  

   }
   else if (IsSame.equals("FALSE")) {

   // commands                    

  }


private String compareOrder(String[] a, String[] b){
String n1 = "TRUE";
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
         if (a[i].equals(b[i])==false) {n1 = "FALSE";}
   }
return n1;  
}
```

It looks ok for me, and it's working for my mobile, but maybe the code is not so normal and it cause wrong results in other devices. So, I need help, if you see something strange and not working in my code, tell me. Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you get a report that this piece of code goes wrong, do you get a stacktrace? Why do you suspect this piece of code? Also, there are some... particular styles in your code, like how you use strings to represent true/false, and you initialisations is funky too?

Comment: Just in my game, some people comment that they do correctly the order, but the game says "wrong".. it's kinda strange, they are not so specific and there are not errors so i can post any message here :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't write what is provided already. :-)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
tv.setText(Arrays.equals(order1, combo)? "Equal" : "Unequal");
```