# how to compare int[] array with int in android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I need to compare int[] array with integer values. This code am having

```
int c1[], c2[], c3[];
int count1=0, count2=1, count3=0;
c1 = new int[] { count1 };
c2 = new int[] { count2 };
c3 = new int[] { count3 };
```

Now i need to compare this int[] array with int, that is any array equals 0 then code don't need to execute if not equals then code execute. How to compare ?? help me thanks in advance ? this if condition i tried but it wont execute exactly.

```
if(c1.equals(0))
{
 // skip
}
else 
{
 // execute code
}
```

this above code didn't work.

Comment: i think this question is quite similar [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710947/android-compare-arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
for(int i=0;i<cl.length;i++){
   if(c1[i]==0)
    {
     // skip
    }
   else 
   {
 // execute code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for :

```
if(c1[0] == 0)
{
 // skip
}
else 
{
 // execute code
}
```

Though it's unclear why you need c1 to be an array if it only holds a single integer.

Answer (score 1):

Use c1[0],c1[1] .... and (iterate through loop)

like-

```
if(c1[0]==0)
```